# Flutter pageview widget change the screens parameter and render it, but it doesn't work

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have created an Pageview for my application where I have 3 screens in

```dart
 class Dashboard extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DashboardState createState() => _DashboardState();
}

class _DashboardState extends State<Dashboard> {

  int bottomNavIndex = 0;
  PageController pageController = PageController(initialPage: 0, keepPage: true);
  static String title = "What we offer";
  bool isCollapsed = false
  static Widget home = WhatWeOffer();

  static List<Widget> screens = [
    home,
    CourseName(),
    AboutUsScreen(),
  ];

  static List<String> titles = [
    title,
    "Courses",
    "About us",
  ];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }


  void onHomeChanged (String newTitle, Widget newWidget){
    setState(() {
      home = newWidget;
      title = newTitle;
      // pageViewKey.currentState.widget;
    });
  }

  void onPageChanged (int index){
    setState(() {
      bottomNavIndex = index;
      title = titles[index];
      // log("page changed $bottomNavIndex  $index");
    });
  }



@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: _onPopScope,
      child: Stack(
        children: [


          /// Drawer
          Container(
            color: Colors.white,
            width: 0.6*Device.width,
            child: Drawer(
                child: ListView(
                  // Important: Remove any padding from the ListView.
                  padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    SizedBox(height : 30),
                    DrawerHeader(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        border: Border(bottom: BorderSide(color: Device.appColor, width: 3.0)),
                        image: DecorationImage(fit: BoxFit.fitWidth, image : AssetImage('assets/images/logo_with_text.jpg')),
                      ),

                      // TODO: add hello user
                      child: Stack(
                          children: [
                            Positioned(bottom : 5.0,child: Text('')),
                          ]
                      ),
                    ),


                    ListTile(
                      leading: FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.gavel),
                      title: Text('Terms & Conditions'),
                      onTap: () {
                        /// carefully change the onPageChanged index
                        onHomeChanged("Terms & Conditions",TnC());
                        onPageChanged(0);
                        pageController.jumpToPage(bottomNavIndex);
                        isCollapsed = false;
                        // Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/tnC');
                      },
                    ),


                  ],
                )

            ),
          ),
          AnimatedPositioned(
            top: isCollapsed ? 0.0*Device.height : 0,
            bottom: isCollapsed ? 0.0*Device.height : 0,
            left : isCollapsed ? 0.6*Device.width : 0,
            right : isCollapsed ? -0.4*Device.width : 0,
            duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
            child: Scaffold(

            appBar: AppBar(
              leading: IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    isCollapsed = !isCollapsed;
                  });
                },
              ),
              backgroundColor: Device.appColor,
              title: Text(
                title,
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontSize: 20,
                ),
              ),
              centerTitle: true,
            ),
            

            body: PageView(
              // key: pageViewKey,
              children: screens,
              controller: pageController,
              onPageChanged: onPageChanged,
            ),


            bottomNavigationBar: CurvedNavigationBar(
              buttonBackgroundColor: Colors.green,
              animationCurve: Curves.easeInOutCirc,
              height: 50,
              color: Device.appColor,
              index: bottomNavIndex,
              backgroundColor: Device.whiteColor,
              items: [
                Icon(Icons.home_filled, color : Colors.white),
                FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.book, color : Colors.white),
                Icon(Icons.person_pin, color : Colors.white),
              ],

              onTap: (index) => setState(() {
              bottomNavIndex = index;
              pageController.jumpToPage(bottomNavIndex);
              }),
            ),
              

        ),
          ),
    ]
      ),
    );
  }
```

[Code][1]

I have a drawer which has various list tiles and I want that on click of a tile, I want to replace the first screen of my pageview with new widget, for this change I have created a parameter home and passed to screens list as shown in code.

I have created a function onHomeChanged for that:

But on clicking it i still see the old widget there?
How do I achieve replacing the old widget with new widget?

I think the pageview widget has created the widget in the memory which is not replaced further, what is the solution to it.

I have tried using pageview key i.e global key, but I am not confident on it, guide me.

Comment: Hi There. Picture based code is frowned upon in StackOverflow. Update your question with full widget code instead of images.

Comment: Also, try wrapping the code inside your `onTap` inside a `setState`. `onTap: () => setState(() { /* Your code here */ })`.

Comment: Ok, now full code is entered

Comment: I have added an answer. Check it out. Hope it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have multiple variables in your state and you are updating only few of them and not the dependant ones.

For example, you have changed your `home` inside your `onHomeChanged` function, but the `screens` variable is still holding your old `home` value.

Also, you have changed `title` in the same function, but your `titles` array is still holding the older `title` value.

So change your `onHomeChanged` function to this.

```
void onHomeChanged (String newTitle, Widget newWidget){
  setState(() {
    home = newWidget;
    title = newTitle;
    
    // With this line, now we are also updating the screens to have the new value of home
    screens = [home, CourseName(), AboutUsScreen()];

    // With this line, now we are also updating the titles to have the new value of title
    titles = [title, "Courses", "About us"];
  });
}
```

This should solve your problem as of now.